# Mapping To a Property from a Dictionary Entry

Tags: c#, dictionary, asp.net-core, automapper

I have two objects. ObjectA contains 2 string properties, the other ObjectB contains 3 string properties and 2 dictionary properties. I am using automapper to map from ObjectB a dictionary value based on a key to a property in ObjectA.

I am trying to map A.payload["reportId"] to B.ReportID

Not really sure what I am missing here.

```
public class ObjectA
{
    public string customerId { get; set; }
    public string consumerId { get; set; }
    public string eventType { get; set; }
    public string eventId { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<string, string> payload { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<string, string> webhookData { get; set; }

}

public class ObjectB
{
    public string CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string ReportID { get; set; }
}

CreateMap<ObjectA, ObjectB>()
                .ForMember(desc => desc.CustomerID, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.customerId))
                .ForMember(desc => desc.ReportID, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.payload.ContainsKey("reportId") ? src.payload["reportId"] : ""));
```

I get the following error:

> Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below. Add a
>   custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify
>   the source/destination type For no matching constructor, add a no-arg
>   ctor, add optional arguments, or map all of the constructor parameters
>   AutoMapper created this type map for you, but your types cannot be
>   mapped using the current configuration. ObjectA -> ObjectB
>   (Destination member list) ObjectA -> ObjectB (Destination member list)
>   Unmapped properties: ReportID

Comment: Which version of AutoMapper are you using? If it's older than 8.0, try `ResolveUsing` instead of `MapFrom`. Or upgrade to version 8.0. In version 8.0, `ResolveUsing` is consolidated with `MapFrom` as per the [documentation](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/8.0-Upgrade-Guide.html#resolveusing). Have a look at the other changes if you are planning to upgarde.

Comment: `AutoMapper created this type map for you...`